# How to print to console/log in Visual Studio 11 in C++ in a Metro app?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-8, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2012

I am attempting to figure out how to print to the debugger console/log in a Visual Studio 11 C++ Metro app. I have tried a number of methods to print to the log in a C++ Metro application (cout, Windows.System.Diagnostics, the documentation on MSDN and the Metro development site).

How do I print to the console?

Comment: presumably you are aware of the following: "Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview is prerelease software and should not be used in production scenarios."

Comment: A platform independent Metro App?  You're not even using C++.

Comment: @Mitch - Understood, but they still have to have a way to output to the console. The documentation is still being put together by MS. This is a simple task, but I haven't found it while browsing the documentation and tutorials over the past week. The docs on C++ in Metro are particularly parse.

Comment: @Hans - Ok, bad phrasing on my part. I edited the post to be more concise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`OutputDebugString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/aa363362):

> Sends a string to the debugger for display.

Some of the Windows API is usable from a Metro style app, including this function.  You can find a list of other diagnostic-related Windows API functions available from Metro style apps [on the Windows Dev Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205755).

Comment: I knew it was going to be something this simple. The trace functions are on that page as well. That page is firmly bookmarked. Thank you, sir.

Comment: The Certification report told me I can't use that for a Metro app (probably because WinRT doesn't support it) :|

Comment: @Cippyboy:  What was the exact text of the error reported by WACK (the certification tool)?  The function is expressly documented as being callable from a Windows Store app, so WACK should not complain.

Comment: I think I should try that again as I didn't had the 2 needed options (C++ -> Consume Windows Runtime Extension and General->Windows Store App Support) turned on for ALL MY LIBRARY PROJECTS. I couldn't even use strlen previously as it linked to kernel32.dll . After I added those 2, everything was supposedly fine.